# How to display text on fixed screen location in openlayers 3

Tags: css, openlayers-3

I use the following code to display coordinates as mouse moves on a map.
Binding event

```
...
map.on('pointermove', getCoordinates);
....
```

and displaying coordinates

```
function getCoordinates(evt) {
  var out = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(evt.coordinate);  
  $('#coordinates').text(out);
}
```

The result is like

[image]

What I want to do is move the div, where the coordinates are displayed, on the map and ideally at the lower left map corner, something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want.  The easiest is to get the overlay container within ol3 and append your div in there.

```
$('#coordinates').appendTo(
  $('.ol-overlaycontainer')
);
```

and control the position of your div using css (absolute position, left and bottom).

```
#coordinates {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: .5em;
  left: .5em;
}
```

See it live: https://jsfiddle.net/b3k6buw8/5/

An other way is to create a custom control out of it and use `map.addControl()`, which basically adds it to the same overlay container div and you can control its position with CSS too.

FYI, there's already a `MousePosition` control within OL3.  Maybe it could interest you.  http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/mouse-position.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlosgr/b3k6buw8/3/). It simply moves the div from the top to the bottom. I haven't look at customcontrol.

Comment: You forgot to add the absolute position, left and bottom CSS properties.  Here's an updated JSFiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/b3k6buw8/5/.  I updated the answer.